# How to use push model in leaflet realtime js api

Tags: javascript, jquery, gps, leaflet

On leaflet-realtime [website](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime) the example is for pull model for realtime tracking of gps. There is an instruction that it can be used with push model. Is there any example for push model?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime/blob/gh-pages/busses.js

Although as mentioned [here](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-realtime/issues/43) this example will not work but enough to get understanding of push model in leaflet